# Random Elements in a List - Python

Tags: python, random, while-loop

So my function **RandList(n)** is supposed to return a list with *n* elements. However, when I run it, it gives me **2 * n** the elements in list L. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
import random

def randList(n):
  counter = 0
  L =[]
  while counter < n:
    L += str(random.randrange(0,100))
    counter += 1
  return L

print randList(1)
print randList(5)
print randList(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `L += str(random.randrange(0,100))`, Python interpreter realized that `str(random.randrange(0,100))` is an iterable, so it added all elements from it (all characters, because it's a string) to `L`.

Try `L += [str(random.randrange(0,100))]` or `L.append(str(random.randrange(0,100)))`.

Final code:

```
def randList(n):
    counter = 0
    L = []
    while counter < n:
        L += [str(random.randrange(0,100))]
        counter += 1
    return L
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `append` instead:

when you do `list += string` you are essentially adding all the characters of the string as separate elements of the list. (`[] + 'hello' --> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`)

Correct Code

```
import random

def randList(n):
    counter = 0
    L =[]
    while counter < n:
        L.append(str(random.randrange(0,100)))
        counter += 1
    return L

print randList(1)
print randList(5)
print randList(10)
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: @Louis, Ah yes Sorry. Done. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Always pay attention when you compare (sum, multiply...) non-homogeneous types.
frostnational and sshashank124 explained why your code was failing.
Here are two shorter solutions (depending on your use case):

```
import random

lr = [random.randrange(0, 101) for i in range(n)]  # has repetitions
lnr = random.sample(range(101), n)  # has no repetition
```

Note that these lists doesn't contain strings, but you can easily adjust the code.
Also note that lr is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).